# Вызов переменной из класса в Python

Tags: python

Как мне вызвать переменную `name` из этого класса?

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, age):
        self.age = age
    def agetell(self):
        return 'Тебе %d лет.' % (self.age)
    def tell(self, name):
        self.name = name
        return 'Привет %s, которому %d лет.' % (self.name, self.age)
```

Comment: Нужно прямо в вопросе предоставлять [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), поэтому, пожалуйста, код из ссылки перенесите в вопрос

Comment: Советую, поля задавать в конструкторе (`__init__`), например `self.name = None`. Т.к. в текущем виде только после вызова `tell` переменная будет доступна: `x = Example(13)` `x.tell('Vasya')` `print(x.name)`

Comment: Ты нигде её не присвоил, кроме как в функции которую ты вызываешь чтобы ее "вызвать". т.е. `ex.tell("имя")`(ex = экземпляр класса Example), нужно было до этого вместо `self.name = name`, присвоить её другим способом.

Answer (score 1):

```py
так

x = Example()
print(x.name)
```